# targeting a li with javascript without a ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a mobile nav, that looks like this

```
<ul id="mobile-menu" class="menu>
    <li class="normal-link"><a href="blabla">link-1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-link"><a href="blabla">link-2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="link-of-dropdown><a href="blabla">blabla</a></li>
            <li class="link-of-dropdown><a href="blabla">blabla</a></li>
            <li class="link-of-dropdown><a href="blabla">blabla</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-link"><a href="blabla">link-3</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="link-of-dropdown><a href="blabla">blabla</a></li>
            <li class="link-of-dropdown><a href="blabla">blabla</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="normal-link"><a href="blabla">link-1</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I cant change the html/wordpress generated code, but I can add css and javascript. So is there a way for me to get next to the dropdown-link's a image that will let the submenu free. if the image is pushed the image will change. if pushed again it will go back to the normal image and the dropdown dissappears again?

I am mostly looking for answer for the problem with of javascript on the dropdown link's but just so you know what i want to do with it.

Comment: I don't get it, are you targetting a div or not?

Comment: no the <li class="dropdown-link">

Comment: why not just use `li.dropdown-link` in CSS , in JQ `$("li.dropdown-link")` or even `$('li').hasClass("dropdown-link")` or with javascript `document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-link")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not really clear but if you want to retrieve an element without using id, first you may use their classes

```
var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName("classname"); //returns a nodeList like array
myClass[0] //first element with "classname"
```

You may also use tag names

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
divs[2] //third "divs"
```

You may also use querySelectorAll, this works pretty much like CSS selector and also returns a nodeList

```
var qs = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This question is so very, very vague. But I guess you're looking for the nth-child() selector.

See the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) for more information. Target your 'mobile-menu' ul, and use nth-child to select the li elements within.

My big question would be, why can't you change the HTML? If it's Wordpress, you can modify the template to change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class and use the Jquery class selector: `$(".class-name")` to target a specific `<li>`